# Preview User Created Code in UIWebView (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiwebview, uitextview, syntax-highlighting

So I'm currently in the midst of creating an HTML Editor for iOS devices and I'm a bit stumped when it comes to this issue. Basically a user can edit HTML code, then I want them to have to have the option to preview their written code (UITextView most likely, but not guaranteed because I may add syntax highlighting) via a UIWebView.

I've seen this used a couple times in different apps on the App Store and I have managed to build an HTML code previewer myself on my website, but I'm looking for more of a local/offline solution.

Also for those of you whom haven't discovered, I would like the WebView to be in a different view (probably via NavigationController), apart from the TextView.

Thanks

---

**EDIT:** So I have a UITextView in my AddViewController, and it's string is named *txtNotes*. Now whatever content that has been entered into the TextView (*txtNotes*), I want to load it in the UIWebView located in a different view named PreviewController. Would I push something from the AddViewController into the UIWebView? For example..

**AddViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction) switchPage:(id)sender {
    // Switches to PreviewController
    if(self.previewController == nil)
    {
    PreviewController *viewTwo = [[PreviewController alloc]
                                                initWithNibName:@"PreviewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.previewController = viewTwo;
        [viewTwo release];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.previewController animated:YES];

    // Possibly add something here?
}
```

Please supply code if you can!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just set the HTML of the WebView using the HTML generated by the user. I don't remember the method, but I think you call the method to set the HTML, rather than loading a request.

Comment: Well if anyone knows anything about this in detail, please do tell! Thanks Andrew :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTML is stored as an NSString, you can use

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

If it is NSData then use

```
- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

with a mime type of `@"text/html"`.

`baseURL` refers to a directory, if you have any CSS or images that the HTML references.